# stop playing next video "onended" (jquery, userscript)

Tags: html5-video, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm very new to Jquery and I'm trying to write some small userscripts to change annoying functions on some websites. I've already written some scripts for youtube that changes some things like autoplay next video mostly with help of other postings on stackoverflow. Now I have a problem with a small script on http://www.focus.de/gesundheit/videos/imbiss-schwindel-kalbs-doener-haeufig-gestreckt_id_6234001.html

after the video stops, the player instantly plays the next video. I've found an onended attribute in the source code. I think it has something to do with this but I've tried some things and it didnt work :(  I just want that the video stops and nothing happens after that.

```
<video id="fwid1contentElement" onplaying="tfmsuite('#fwid1').tfmvideo('onPlaying');" onended="tfmsuite('#fwid1').tfmvideo('onEnded');" onpause="tfmsuite('#fwid1').tfmvideo('onPause');" onstalled="tfmsuite('#fwid1').tfmvideo('onStalled');" controls="controls" src="http://videos2.focus.de/wochit/2016/11/21/583314e4e4b0aa0940a027be-1280x720_Nov_21_2016_15_43_48.MP4" data-flashblockwhitelisted="true" height="720" width="1280"></video>
```

would be very nice if someone can help me xD

Answer (score 0):

You have found the `onended` event handler, what is left is to clear its content like so:

```
$('video').attr('onended', '');
```

it will not trigger predefined "play next" logic.